# ibatis access oracle long type data

Tags: ibatis

I used ibatis 2 with the following code:

```
X_long b = (X_long) getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("select_long", id);
```

and mapping:

```
<select id="select_long"
       resultClass="spring_ibatis.domain.X_long">
  select id, txt from x_long
    where ID=#ID#
</select>
```

X_long class is:

```
public class X_long implements Serializable
{
   // ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // Data access methods
   // ////////////////////////////////////////////////
   private String ID;
   private String TXT;
...
}
```

if worked just fine.
Now I switched to mybatis (ibatis 3) with spring with same mapping, same class, and annotation code, I got the following errors:

```
Stream has already been closed
```

Please help!